# May I know how to set up the model for training on GPU?

Tags: audio, pytorch

This is the track separation program on Github, and this is its description:

```
Python version -3.10
To install dependencies, run:
Pip install - r requirements. txt
Additionally, ffmpeg should be installed in the venv
If using ` ` conda [example_vocals. mp3] (..% 2F.% 2F.% 2FDownloads% 2Fexample_vocals. mp3), you can run:
Conda install - c conda forge ffmpeg
All scripts should be run from src directory
Train/evaluation/reference pipelines support GPU acceleration To activate it, specify the following env variable:
Export CUDA_ VISIBLE_ DEVICES={DEVICE-NUM}
```

I don't know the final `Export CUDA_ VISIBLE_` How to set it up? My platform is Windows, and using export on the terminal will result in an error. Some people search the network and say 'set', but I am not sure if I have successfully set it up. That is to say, I don't know if I should enter a command in the terminal to change the `{DEVICE NUM}` variable, or if I should set it elsewhere in `pychar`. If I should enter a command in the terminal to set it up, What command should I fill in, `{DIVICE NUM}`, should I change to `{CPU0}`, `{CUDA}`, or `{CPU}`, or should I not use that parenthesis? How can I know after making the changes that I have successfully made

I hope someone can tell me how to set up the program correctly to run on the GPU and how to verify if the setup is successful.